# Variables don't work in shell_exec() I can't find the mistake

Tags: php

For some reason I can't use variables in `shell_exec`. I already tried changing `'` to `"` but that wouldn't work either.

**This works:**

```
<?php
shell_exec('curl --request PUT --data "{\"on\":true, \"bri\":200}" http://192.168.178.21/api/cWRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/lights/2/state');
?>
```

**But This doesn't:**

```
<?php
$status = true;
shell_exec('curl --request PUT --data "{\"on\":$status, \"bri\":200}" http://192.168.178.21/api/cWRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/lights/2/state');
?>
```

Comment: so, what is your question ?

Comment: The question was how i would get it working with variables.

Comment: Variables are not parsed when inserted into as string quoted via `'`. `echo "$status"` will output `true`, while `echo '$status'` will output `$status`

Comment: PHP provides direct access to curl_* functions. There shouldn't be a need to shell those commands out in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to concat the strings. Since php displays `true` to `1`, you might want an intermediate variable to set the value of `true` to `"true"`

```
<?php
$status = true;
$string_status = $status ? 'true' : 'false';
shell_exec('curl --request PUT --data "{\"on\":' . $string_status . ', \"bri\":200}" http://192.168.178.21/api/cWRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/lights/2/state');
?>
```

You can't directly pass variables in a single-quote delimited string. You have to close that string, concat, then re-open.

in example :

```
<?php
$myVar = "world";
echo "Hello $myVar"; //displays : Hello world
echo 'Hello $myVar'; //displays : Hello $myVar
```

If you want to use double quote delimited string in your `shell_exec()`, you'll have to escape the double quotes already in it, such as :

```
<?php
$status = true;
$string_status = $status ? 'true' : 'false';
shell_exec("curl --request PUT --data \"{\\\"on\\\":$string_status, \\\"bri\\\":200}\" http://192.168.178.21/api/cWRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/lights/2/state");
?>
```

But that will quickly become unreadable (you'll have to escape the single quotes, and the `\"` will become `\\\"`

Comment: Both versions don't work for me...i feel stupid....

Comment: ok...i did $status= "true"; and it worked. Thank you for your help. (I tried both versions...both work with "true".